# Obtain rate of change of an exponential without using numerical analysis

Tags: limits, derivatives

I though i was very good at math till i met [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjtIz.png) equation

$$Y=X\times (1.01)^X$$

If $X= [1,2,3,...]$ then $Y=[1.01, 2.0402, 3.0909,...]$

I expected that the rate of change should be $dY=[0.01,0.0402,0.0909,...]$ but when i differentiated it, the answer was extremly different. this can be clarified more without numbers.

The mathematical derivative of the above image is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrI9S.png)
But the actual change is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvU72.png).

I do not understand "what i do not understand".

1. Why is the rate of change (derivative...) does not give me the same as what i have done above (very similar to limits).
2. What kind of math branch do I need to study or see or understand to conceptualize the very big gap between what i understand and the reality.

Edit 1:

This is related to something called natural growth (e.g., half life time equation)

Edit 2:

The Equation was obtained from this sentence: write an equation that describes accumulative interest of 1%. In another words, AccInterest $= ((X(1.01)+X)(1.01)) +X)(1.01)...$

Comment: You're subtracting the $Y$ values and $X$ values to get the change in $Y$?

Comment: Sorry? i am not subtracting any Y.

Comment: I edited the question in a manner to make it more understandable. for example how did i obtain the equation in the first place (hoping it would help)

Comment: X here is just like the Initial value in the half life time equation; if it is not used (i.e, `y = 1.01^x -1` this will just give you the increasing "percentage" not the actual increment.

Comment: You said "I expected that the rate of change should be..." It appears that you're getting these values by subtracting the $Y$ and the $X$ (that's not how you get the change in $Y$)

Comment: I'm sorry, where am i subtracting Y & X? i am just subtracting X from Y (i.e. dy = Y - X)

Comment: $Y-X$ is not a measurment for the change in $Y$. You should be subtracting two consecutive $Y$ values to get the change in $Y$. Also, don't feel like you're bad at math because you struggled with a problem. Struggling with math problems is normal and all part of the learning process. If you're not stuggling, then you're not really learning.

Comment: Please see my last example in edit 2 (i re edited it). all i want to know is the branch of math that i can study that will further support me. Thank you for the support :) it was kind.

Comment: Your computation of the derivative (second "this") is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust please, illustrate how am i wrong.

Comment: What rules did you use ?

Comment: I implemented what i understood to an equation. I thought your assumption(that I'm wrong) is that my differentiation procedures are wrong. Execuse my clumsiness and little knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The equation in the picture,
$$
Y = X \times 1.01 ^X
$$
is not the equation for constant growth at the rate of $1\%$ for each time interval. That equation is
$$
Y = s \times 1.01^X
$$
where $Y$ represents the amount at time $X$ and $s$ is the amount you started with at time $X=0$.

To find the half life you let $Y=2s$ and try to find $X$. The answer will be about $X=70$. To find it more precisely you need to experiment with various values or learn about logarithms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i revised your values and X=35 yields a value of 1.41 (and instead it was supposed to give 2)

Comment: The Half life time is denoted as $A=(A_0)(0.5)^t$ where t is the unit of change (in this case it is time) and $A_0$ is the initial value and when substituting those in; you yield $A$; that is what i do not understand, why do yo substitute $Y$?

Comment: @OmarShawky Sorry. The $35$ should be $70$. I edited to fix this typo. The number comes from the "rule of 70" which says that the doubling time is approximately $70$ divided by the interest rate (as a percent).

Comment: Thank you so much. If i might continue asking, is this formula suitable (as ananswer to edit 2) $Y=X\sum_0^n{(1.01)^n}$?

Comment: No. The equation you are looking for is the one in my answer. That formula is not right. (We can't carry on this conversation in comments.)

Comment: Sorry for that. I understand now what you wrote especially after i seqrched everything up. What you wrote is the exponential growth of $Y$ with initial value $X$ and interest (or increasing rate) of 0.01. (this can be further illustrated using something called "cumulative interest", it further more uses one more parameter which is $\frac{r}{X}$ (i can illustrate why but only if you need). The equation mentioned above is right but your usage (specifically in the half life time) is wrong. Simply, how could $Y$ decrease if $r>0$? Impossible! 1.01 means it increases! Hope I'm helpful